# Property null is read-only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

It might not be the null property, but here's what's up:
Let's say I have this code -

```
1. someclipthatsinanarray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arrayframe);
2. function arrayframe(e:Event):void
3. {
4. e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arrayframe);
5. e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(e.currentTarget);
6. e.currentTarget = null;
7. }
```

- and pay attention to line six.  I run this in the debugger and get this error:

```
Error 1119: Line 6, arrayframe: Property is read - only.
```

What is read only?  If null is read - only, then why?

Comment: When an assignment says that it can't do anything because of read only, it usually refers to the left hand operand, so it says `e.currentTarget` is read-only in your example. I have no idea about actionscript to help you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.currentTarget` is a property of your event. It is read-only because an event should not be modified after having been dispatched.

Don't worry though, as soon as all the functions listening to this particular event are finished executing their code, the reference to your clip stored in the event will be garbage collected.

Comment: So, what you are saying, is that I should call = null AFTER I call removeEventListener?  Is that not what I am doing?

Comment: No he's saying you don't need `= null` at all, as once the event has been handled the reference to the `movieclip` you removed is garbage collected.

Comment: Oh, I get it, because at one time I called (if(e.currentTarget == null)) with the same from inside its frame because I was getting an error, but it resulted in a 'false'.

Answer (score 3):

`currentTarget` is a property of the `Event`. It is read only and you cannot modify that property.

Here is what I think you desire to do :

```
someclipthatsinanarray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arrayframe);

// event handler
function arrayframe(e:Event):void
{
    var clip:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    clip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arrayframe);
    clip.parent.removeChild(clip);
    clip = null;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments this line is not doing what you likely believe it is :

`clip = null;`

clip was just a local reference to that MovieClip, just the same as the element in the array is just a reference to the MovieClip. So setting clip to null, is not deleting the MovieClip, it's merely just nulling out our reference, which really is not even needed since it's a local variable and it's scope ends upon completion of the handler.

An object is only truly marked for garbage collection once there are no references to the object remaining.

Also important to note that being on the Display List of another object is considered a reference.

Comment: This is very likely to work, but for some reason I get another error when I call e.currentTarget as MovieClip = null;.  This is the error: 'Error 1050: Cannot assign to a non-reference value'.

Comment: I repeat you CANNOT modify that property. You CAN modify the object that the property references.

Comment: Worth noting that this won't actually null the original object out. Instead, it will just null the memory reference (in this case, `clip`) to that object.

Comment: That is correct and a very good point. No object is marked for garbage collection until there are no remaining references.